# Make file error

Tags: c

-> represents "include"

list.c -> list.h

matrix.c -> matrix.h

smatrix.c -> smatrix.h

smatrix h file -> list.h and matrix.h files

test.c -> test.h

test.h -> list.h, matrix.h, and smatrix.g files

And now I have this makefile

```
all: run

run: test.o list.o matrix.o smatrix.o
    gcc test.o list.o matrix.o smatrix.o -o matrix-mul

list.o: list.c list.h
    gcc -g list.c 

matrix.o: matrix.c matrix.h
    gcc -g matrix.c 

smatrix.o: smatrix.c smatrix.h
    gcc -g smatrix.c 

test.o: test.c test.h
    gcc -g test.c
```

And now I am getting

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_make_matrix", referenced from: //make_matrix defines in matrix.h
      _main in cctU8RoB.o
  "_print_matrix", referenced from://print_matrix defines in list.h
      _main in cctU8RoB.o
  "_make_smatrix", referenced from://make_smatrix defines in smatrix.h
      _main in cctU8RoB.o
  "_multiply_by_vector", referenced from://muliply_by_vector defines in smatrix.h
      _main in cctU8RoB.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

I am calling those functions which are defined in other files in test.c and test.h includes all the header files for the functions called in test.c file. All header files have include gard something liet *filename*

How can I fix this problem??

-edit-
I changed *o file with gcc -c instead of gcc -o and now I am getting

```
matrix.c:33: error: ‘for’ loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode
matrix.c:38: error: ‘for’ loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode
matrix.c:44: error: ‘for’ loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode
matrix.c: In function ‘make_matrix_k’:
matrix.c:58: error: ‘for’ loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode
matrix.c: In function ‘print_matrix’:
matrix.c:73: error: ‘for’ loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode
matrix.c:74: error: ‘for’ loop initial declaration used outside C99 mode

//for loop in matrix.c file
for(size_t i=0; i < height; i++){
        //m->data[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*width);
        m->data[i] = calloc(width, sizeof(int));

        if(m->data[i] == NULL){
            for(size_t j = 0; j < i; j++) free(m->data[j]);
            free(m->data);
            free(m);
            return 0;
        }
        if(opt == nonzero_matrix_k_off){
            for(size_t j = 0; j < width; j++){
                m->data[i][j] = 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

It worked fine with xcode4...How to fix this problem?

Comment: For the *.o files, you need to use `gcc -c -g ...`.

Comment: What happens if you try running the commands in the makefile manually? Where does the first error occur? What exactly did you type, and what error was thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `-c` option to make gcc generate object file and `-o name` to name it. Example:

```
smatrix.o: smatrix.c smatrix.h
    gcc -g -c -o smatrix.o smatrix.c
```

To solve the second problem, add the `-std=c99` switch to gcc parameter list. And, as Evan Mulawski mentioned, you don't need the `-o` switch.

```
smatrix.o: smatrix.c smatrix.h
    gcc -g -std=c99 -c smatrix.c
```

Comment: You cannot use the output file when attempting to compile the output file, i.e. using smatrix.o inside the object file generation of itself.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski: I don't use the file. The `-o smatrix.o` switch means "the name of output file is smatrix.o"

Comment: Great it worked! But could you explain why I need to add smartix.o in the line gcc -g -c -o ...?

Comment: You don't need it, it was my fault. You need it when linking the whole program: to tell the compiler the name of the output file (default is `a.out`). When you create object file with the `-c` option, gcc uses the same name. By passing `-o smatrix.o` you just tell the compiler what it already knows.

Answer (score 0):

As my comment stated, to generate the object files you need to use the `-c` option when calling GCC:

```
list.o:  list.c list.h
         gcc -c -g list.c
```

Note that you DO NOT use the `-o` option until you compile the final program.

You can optionally add `-ansi -pedantic -Wall`, which I find extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

For the new question, gcc defaults to it's own standard and not c99.

If you want your code to conform to c99, add:

-std=c99

else you need to define the loop variable before you use it in the loop.

i.e.

```
void function(size_t height)
{
    size_t i;

    for(i=0;i<height;i++)
    {
     ...
    };
 }
```