# make file, Is this look ok?

Tags: c

```
all: run

run: test.o list.o matrix.o smatrix.o
    gcc test.o list.o matrix.o smatrix.o -o matrix-mul

list.o: list.c list.h
    gcc -g -c list.c 

matrix.o: matrix.c matrix.h
    gcc -g -std=c99 -c -o matrix.o matrix.c

smatrix.o: smatrix.c smatrix.h
    gcc -g -c -o smatrix.o smatrix.c

test.o: test.c test.h
    gcc -g -c test.c
```

I was having lots of problems to make a makefile and I finally got this working. And I just want to make sure these are ok (not just for making program running but in term of a good make file)

One question is that why do matrix.o and smatrix.o have .o files in the line gcc -g -c ... where as list.o and test.o don't have that line..

I had to add -std=c99 because I was getting some weird for loop error but still don't understand why I need to put matrix.o in the line..

Comment: I told you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432486/make-file-error/5432546#5432546 that you don't need specyfying the output name (it was my fault I put it there at first). And the loop thing is not weird, the c90 standard does not support creating local variables everywhere, like in the for loop header, so you switch to the c99 standard which does.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote this before I saw your correction! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file is OK-ish. It is not very easily maintainable.

This website has a really good tutorial on how to make nice makefiles:
http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/

Especially look at the last example:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

This should show you how to enhance maintainability (add extra files to `SOURCES`, and the rest is done automatically.

Comment: The `-Wall` is **highly** reccommended, btw.

Answer (score 1):

The below file supports `make all` `make depend` and `make clean` - you only need to change the first lines. Remember to `make depend` if you change includes in any file.

```
TARGET:=matrix-mul
SOURCES:=test.c list.c matrix.c smatrix.c
OBJECTS:=$(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -std=c99 -Wall
LD=gcc
LDFLAGS=


# First target - simply say that we want to produce matrix-mul
all: $(TARGET)

# To create the target we need all .o files, and we link with LD/LDFLAGS
# $@ is the file we're making, aka matrix-mul
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)

#Creating a .o from a .c
# $< is the c file, $@ is the corresponding .o file
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Regenerate dependencies
depend:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $(SOURCES) > .depend

# Remove produced files
clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET) .depend

# If there's no dependency file, create it
.depend: depend

# Include the autogenerated dependency file
include .depend
```

EDIT: If you want this even more generic, you can replace the SOURCE:= line with:

```
SOURCES:=$(wildcard *.c)
```

This makefile will then simply build TARGET from all .c files in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would highly suggest here would be to add a `clean` target that deletes all your intermediate files (probably all the `.o` files), like so:

```
clean:
    rm *.o
```

For extra credit, put all your `*.o` files in a make variable, and use that variable as the target of the run rule, and after the `rm` command above.

The reason I want you to do this is for debugging purposes. It *could* be that you have one of the above rules wrong, but since you already built all your `.o` files once, it is just picking up an old one every time. If you do a `make clean` before your build, it will catch that.