# Undefined reference for function accepting references to user defined classes

Tags: c++, reference, g++, undefined

I have a problem with a function that accepts as input references to two user defined objects. Here's what it looks like:

```
void copy_job_list( vector<Job> &org, vector<Job> &dest)  
{  
      // ....  
}
```

The function is defined in file `functions.cpp`, and called in `job_random.cpp`, both files include the header in which the declaration of this function is given.

Now when in `job_random.cpp` I call the function with

```
copy_job_list( Old_best_list.J, Old_best_list_new_times.J) ;
```

where `Old.best_list.J` and `Old_best_list_new_times.J` are vectors of type `Job`, I get the following error with g++:

```
job_random.o:job_random.cpp:(.text+0x1fc): undefined reference to 
`copy_job_list(std::vector<Job, std::allocator<Job> >, 
                           std::vector<Job, std::allocator<Job> >&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [random_job] Error 1
```

This looks like linker is convinced only second argument should be a reference, and first should be a value. And indeed if I change definition and declaration of copy_job_list() so that first argument is passed by value, then program compiles. But why would linker insist I do that?

From what I was able to find on the web it seems like undefined reference messages usually mean I didn't include headers the right way or such, but `functions.cpp` contains a multitude of other functions that `job_random.cpp` uses without a hitch, all of them declared through a common header.

Answer (score 3):

You likely have `void copy_job_list( vector<Job> org, vector<Job> &dest)` in a header file, or have it forward declared some other way. Also make sure that your dependencies are right - do a clean build.

Comment: Nope, I just copied over the first line of definition as a declaration. However it indeed seemed to be an issue of 'clean build'. I suspected something along those lines could be a problem, as I did use void copy_job_list( vector<Job> org, vector<Job> &dest) at some point before. Now, after messing a bit with the code and rebuilding everything went through and the program runs, though it's the same thing as 20 minutes ago. Can you please tell me how to ensure that I make a 'clean build' as opposed to whatever else? I'm using mingw32-make with g++.

Comment: Puchatek: You need to generate dependencies, see my sample Makefile in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432877/make-file-is-this-look-ok/5432977#5432977

Comment: Just to make sure - a clean build essentially boils down to deleting all .o files, forcing compiler to create each one anew?

Comment: @Puchatek: all .o files and the executables

Answer (score 0):

First, the error message looks like it's coming from the linker, not the
compiler.  It's just a guess, since you don't show us the code, but I'd
guess that the declaration in the header is missing the &.  (I'm also
curious as to what vector could be.  The error message suggests
std::vector, but that's a template, and the code you show us doesn't
show any use of a template.)

Comment: How about the line: void copy_job_list( vector<Job> &org, vector<Job> &dest) for using a template? :)

Comment: That wasn't what I saw when I responded.  My basic point is that you should copy/paste the actual code (and error message).